# Quiero ocultar inputs según lo que se seleccione en el combobox

Tags: javascript

Tengo una pregunta con un combobox que tienen 2 opciones, ejemplo

CONDICIÓN DEL estudiante con 2 opciones como respuesta

**1.EGRESADO**
**2. NO EGRESADO**

```
  <select name="pregunta[0].ope_id" id="pregunta[0].ope_id" class="form-control selectinput valid">  
            <option value="44" data_arreglo="33,34,35">EGRESADO</option>  
            <option value="45" data_arreglo="32">NO EGRESADO</option>
```

En el campo data_arreglo guardo los id de las preguntas que dependen de la respuesta que elijo y que quiero ocultar.
Acá esta una de las preguntas que quiero ocultar.

```
<input type="hidden" name="pregunta[2].pre_id" id="pregunta[2].pre_id" value="33" data_padre="31">
```

quiero utilizar una función que obtenga el evento y oculte las preguntas.
Gracias de antemano.

Actualmente solo he logrado esto, pero no sirve a mi propósito

```js
var preguntas = document.querySelectorAll('[data-trigger]');
preguntas = [].slice.apply(preguntas);
preguntas.forEach(function(item, i){
 var _trigger = item.attributes['data-trigger'].nodeValue;
  if(_trigger === "true"){
   document.getElementById(item.attributes['id'].nodeValue).addEventListener("change", Disparar);
  }

});

function Disparar(e){
  console.log(e.target.type);
 var id = e.target.attributes['id'].nodeValue;
  switch(e.target.type){
   case 'select-one' : ss_selectOne(id); break;
    default: break;
  }

}

function ss_selectOne(id){
  var hijos = document.querySelectorAll('[data-padre]');
  hijos = [].slice.apply(hijos);
  hijos = hijos.filter(function(item){
   return item.attributes['data-padre'].nodeValue === id;
  });
  hijos.forEach(function(item, i){
   document.getElementById(item.attributes['id'].nodeValue).removeAttribute("disabled");
  });
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var arreglo = element.options[element.selectedIndex].attributes['data-arreglo'].nodeValue.split(',');
  arreglo.forEach(function(item, i){
    if(item !== ""){
     document.getElementById(item).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    }    
  });  

  
}
```

```html
 <select id="31" data-trigger="true">
 <option value="" data-arreglo="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" data-arreglo="33">Egresado</option>
  <option value="2" data-arreglo="32">No Egresado</option>
</select>

<select id="33" data-trigger="false" data-padre="31">
 <option value="" data-arreglo="">Fecha de Egreso</option>
  <option value="1">Fecha de Egreso</option>
</select>
<select id="32" data-trigger="false" data-padre="31">
 <option value="" data-arreglo="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1">Motivo por el cual no ingreso</option>
</select>
<br>
```

Comment: Disculpa ¿Usas Jquery o JavaScript puro?.

Comment: Hola Gabriel, estaba haciendolo con javascript puro.

Answer (score 1):

Recomiendo hacerlo con jquery y clases. Asi podria quedar el código:

```
<select name="pregunta[0].ope_id" id="pregunta[0].ope_id" class="form-control selectinput valid" onchange="cambia_visibles()>  
    <option value="44" data_class="egresado">EGRESADO</option>  
    <option value="45" data_class="no_egresado">NO EGRESADO</option>
</select>
```

Los inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="pregunta[2].pre_id" id="pregunta[2].pre_id" value="33" data_padre="31" class="mostrar egresado">  
<input type="text" name="pregunta[2].pre_id" id="pregunta[2].pre_id" value="34" data_padre="31" class="mostrar egresado">  
<input type="text" name="pregunta[2].pre_id" id="pregunta[2].pre_id" value="35" data_padre="31" class="mostrar egresado">  
<input type="text" name="pregunta[2].pre_id" id="pregunta[2].pre_id" value="36" data_padre="31" class="mostrar no_egresado">
```

y la funcion que los oculta:

```
function cambia_visibles() {
    valor = $("#pregunta[0].ope_id")..attr("data_class");
    $(".mostrar").show();
    $("."+valor).hide();
}
```

Comment: Gracias Alfredo, lo que sucede es que lo manejo con un arreglo porque las preguntas son dinámicas y se configuran en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Para que se respete tu código es necesario agregar el **onchange="cambia_visibles();"**:

```
<select name="pregunta[0].ope_id" id="pregunta[0].ope_id" class="form-control selectinput valid" onchange="cambia_visibles();">  
    <option value="44" data_arreglo="33,34,35">EGRESADO</option>  
    <option value="45" data_arreglo="32">NO EGRESADO</option>  
</select>
```

Prueba la siguiente funcion:

```
function cambia_visibles() {
    var valores = $('option:selected', this).attr('data_arreglo');
    var valores_array = valores.split(',');
    $(".mostrar").show();
    $("."+valor).hide();
    for(var i = 0; i < valores_array.length; i++) {
        var select_input = "input[value="+valores_array[i]+"]"
        $(select_input).closest('input').hide();
    }
}
```

Los inputs deben ir como **text**:

```
<input type="text" name="pregunta[2].pre_id" id="pregunta[2].pre_id" value="33" data_padre="31">
```

Answer (score 0):

He aquí una manera, aparatosa cuanto menos, de llegar al `select` que deseas y añadir el evento *change* sin hacerlo explícitamente en el *html*:

```
window.onload = function(){
                var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
                for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
                    var element = selects[i];                    
                    if(element.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].value == "44"){
                       element.addEventListener("change",function(){
                            //aqui ocultas los inputs :)
                       });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function funcionlogicapreguntas(selc,preid) {
        @{
            foreach (var hr in logica)
            {
                var hcont = hr.pre_id_sec_id_Habilita.Split(',');
                var classnameocult = hr.tipo_sec_pre.GetValueOrDefault() ? ".divnamepregunta" : ".divnameseccion";
                var classnamecontent = "";
                foreach (var h in hcont)
                {
                    if (classnamecontent == string.Empty)
                    {
                        classnamecontent = classnamecontent + classnameocult + h;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        classnamecontent = classnamecontent +","+ classnameocult + h;
                    }
                }
                @:if (preid == "@hr.pre_id" && $(selc).val()=="@hr.ope_id"){
                @:$("@classnamecontent").show();
                @:} else {
                @:$("@classnamecontent").hide();
                @:}
            }
        }
```